# How can I rotate photos of furniture a few degrees in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, 3d, rotation, real-estate

I'm trying to help a friend of mine sell his house. I'm hoping to be able to use Photoshop to insert a table and chairs into one of his empty rooms, to help people visualize what the room could look like furnished.

[Here's](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7607/woodenchair1.jpg) a picture of one of the chairs I'm trying to rotate. I have several other chairs that are front and side facing.

I understand that this is a 2 dimensional image and I'm trying to rotate it in 3 dimensions. The data for the third dimension isn't there, so when I try to use the 3d rotate tool in Photoshop, it doesn't work properly.

I'm not trying to rotate these pieces of furniture very far, however (maybe 5-25 degrees).

1) Is this something that can be accomplished with Photoshop? If so, how?

2) If not, is there any other way to do it? How involved would it be to convert something like this into a 3d model so it could be rotated? I have a trial version of 3ds Max that I can use for the next few weeks but I don't know where to start.

Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to read (and hopefully respond to) my question!

Comment: Are you asking if something like the photo explorer a la Blade Runner exists for Photoshop? BTW, a 25 degree rotation is like a 7% rotation...which is not insignificant.

Comment: I don't know the reference, but I don't think the down-vote was necessary. I'm just trying to figure out if this is possible. Any constructive comments are welcome!

Comment: Okay, I get the point from the two down-votes...  this isn't possible. Thank you SE.

Comment: You answered this yourself - there is no information to rotate the chairs in 3D. You can either try modelling it in 3DS, or find a similar chair and photograph it yourself at the appropriate angle.

Comment: @JackT: I never downvoted you. I was asking an honest question, for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1) No
- 2) Modelling from this refrence. If you can take more photos of this chair you can create 3d model from this photos with autodesk new product http://www.123dapp.com/catch.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution is always the simplest!
Borrow or rent a good looking chair from one of yor friends.  Put it in the house your friend is selling and take a picture...  It would all be done in a couple of hours.
Isn't this way simpler then spending the next couple of weeks learning 3DStudio Max?

If you are going the 3DS Max route, just make sure it does not end up like [this](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2011/jun/29/chinese-county-ridicule-doctored-photograph)

Comment: Hah, the easiest solution is always the simplest...  love it. Yes, that would be easier, and I just might give in and do it. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

you have to take another picture and if you want to use photoshop then use cs4 and above create your own 3d chair and rotate as much as you want..

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer but I'm not sure what you mean. If you could elaborate, that would be great!

Comment: if you just want to rotate a picture then see this tutorial
http://www.cbtcafe.com/photoshop/rotatingimages/rotating.htm
and if you want to change the direction then you have take another picture and you can design your own image... in photoshop 3d.